# getDrawable returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

Pff, this is one of these things that ruins your schedule, but you don't wanna give up. Since 2 days some of my bitmap resources don't load and show up in my app anymore. I nailed it down to the getDrawable() returning null on the supplied ResID.

I'm running this on Genymotion Nexus 5 with API 22, or a Nexus 5 physical device. For my project I mainly use the following to load drawables.

**ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), drawableID, null);**

But because of this issue I also tried *context.getDrawable(id)* and *getResources().getDrawable(id, getTheme())*. Each method returns null.

Other things that might be interesting:

- Resource is in my project (in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi && xxhdpi)
- file-name's are correct (xxx_yyy_zzz.png)
- Clean project / deleted build products
- Got old image files from my repo: Doesn't load
- Resource have been copied and renamed: Doesn't load.
- Open the resources in my Image Editor and saved as brand new files: Doesn't load.
- Copied resources into empty dummy project: They actually show!
- 90% of my resources load perfectly, it's just a few larger bitmaps given issues.
- The image does show in Android Studio Layout preview (Nexus 5, Api 22)
- I've included some tests (like the copies), occasionally they actually load, but that's rare. The image I really care about never loads.

I also tried stepping into the Android Code and get these on getDrawable(id):

- throw new IllegalStateException("Override configuration has already been set") (ContextThemeWrapper.java)
- in AssetManager.java , getResourceValue I see a parameter being passed of type TypedValue with a string "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/{image_name}.png"

The latter raises some alarm bells as well, cause I don't have a folder with that -v4 suffix, so I wonder why it creates that. But stepping through that code in Android Studio doesn't really make sense to me as stepping into a method usually drops me right in a comment block of Android.

Anyway, I hope someone had some weird issues with image resources as well and might be able to point me in the right direction as to why this is happening. The fact that the image isn't corrupt and I really don't see anything wrong in my method calling or resources-folders, makes my kinda out of options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only time this has ever happened to me was when I placed the image I was trying to load into my mipmap folder instead of the normal drawables folder.

When you begin typing R.drawable. can you see your drawable?

Comment: Yes, auto-complete immediately finds all my drawables, including the ones not loading as soon as I type R.drawable. The resources are actually in the drawable-mdpi (and other variants as mentioned in question) - folders.